# Salesforce Api implementation on iPhone

Tags: iphone, salesforce

I am implementing salesforce api in my project. I downloaded code from the below link

https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-iOS

**But the problem is that i want this api on iPhone not on iPad.**
When i am going to convert it on iPhone. I am fail. It is typical to convert it because of difference of code like split view etc.
I dont want split view just simple api. If you guys source code of it then share. Thanks.

(Note: I am using xcode not phonegap)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing yourself by looking at the sample app, the actual api library itself doesn't use splitviews as far as i know. Concentrate on what's in the ZKSforce directory, and not the sample SVNTest app.

Comment: Ok can you suggest me how i integrade just saleforce login form, After login, i will get account through query:

"select Id, Name from Account"? can you do this or give me any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: look at ZKSforce/FDCOAuthViewController