# how to post data on salesforce database from iphone application?

Tags: iphone, salesforce

I am developing one iPhone application in which I want to post data on the salesforce database.
I have tried from google but not got any success.

Can you please guide me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please check this question, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960347/salesforce-api-implementation-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce provides an iOS SDK to talk to their API:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

Here is a tutorial on getting started:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_iOS

You will need to use an Oauth flow to authenticate to the API. This means you show a Login page from Salesforce.com, the user logs in, and then your UIWebView will get a redirect with a sessionId in the URL. You can extract the sessionId and use it to talk to the API for read or write access, depending on the user's permissions. The SDK includes sample code that implements all of that, so you just need to merge that code in with your app.